# ibmcloud create action through cli

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions, ibm-cloud-plugin

`ibmcloud` create action through `cli` is not working . Getting an exception

> Unable to authenticate with Cloud Functions: Unable to obtain wsk
>   authentication key for Org 'xxxxx' and Space 'xxxx': Target Org
>   'xxxxm' and Space 'xxxx' do not have an auth key; if Space 'dev' was
>   recently created, try again in a couple minutes.

But I have logged in successfully using `ibmcloud` login command

Comment: Issue is while executing the command 'ibmcloud fn action create hello hello.js '

Comment: Please provide the command syntax you are using. Have you set the org and space with `ibmcloud target --cf`?

Comment: I first ran ibmcloud login.. and gave details . Then set the target using ibmcloud target --cf. It set my org and space.Then created a file named hello.js with content. Then I tried to ran ibmcloud fn action create hello hello.js

Comment: Add the details to the question. Also, add the output from `ibmcloud target`

Comment: Issue is resolved now. There was a conflict of location and spaces. Upgraded the accout and created another space in correct region and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Issue is resolved now. The account I created at IBM was lite account where the initial credentials were created with different location. But my ibmcloud login was picking another location api. Even if i could give the api enpoint manually, org and space was not matching. Since it was a Lite account, there was no permission to add another org and space. AFter sending mail to IBM, I could add my credit card details and I could create a new space and creating action worked now